# Empty content when moving files of a folder to another folder with a modification or deletion of stop words on these files

Tags: python

[image]

I have this project.

I have a folder called "Corpus" and it contains a set of files.
It is required that I delete the "stop words" from these files and then save the new files that do not contain the stop words in a new folder called "Save-files".

And when I opened the “Save-Files” folder, I saw inside it the files that I had saved, but they were without content, that is, when I open the number one file, it is empty without content.

And as it is clear in the first picture, here is the “Save-Files” folder, and inside it there is a group of files that i saved.

And when I open any of the files, it is empty.

How can I solve the problem?

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import os

stoplist = stopwords.words('english')

dir_path = 'C:/Users/Super/Desktop/IR/homework/Lab4/corpus/corpus/'
save_dir = "C:/Users/Super/Desktop/IR/homework/Lab4/corpus/"


for document in os.listdir(dir_path):
    with open(dir_path + document, "r") as reader:
        save_file = open(save_dir + document, 'w')
        text = reader.read()
        cleaned = [word for word in text.split() if word not in 
           stoplist]
        print(cleaned)
```

Comment: You are printing the output but you never write it to your file... 
`save_file.write(cleaned)` 

Also consider using `with open` as @Aanish mentions because it is much safer.

Comment: i edit it , but not solve.

Comment: You have to `write()` to the file.

Comment: Yes, I edit my comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to update the line to read the file to

```
file = open(dir_path + document, "r")
```

Moreover, there is a better way to do this entirely, you could use the 'with' key word to open, read, write and close files, like this;

```
with open(dir_path + document, "r") as reader:
    text = reader.read()
```

The same goes for the write file as well. Infact the 'with' keyword closes the file when you move out of the indentation. This is very important since in many cases we forget to close the file, which causes inconsistencies while successive reads and writes to the same file. Also, remember to add the type in which you want to open the file 'r' means read mode, 'w' means write mode.

Comment: I add this line save_file.writelines(["%s\n" % item  for item in cleaned]) and it's solved.